# using xml2js in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, xml2js

I am using a protractor application with typescript where I am converting an XML file to JSON format; I have a few questions :

Here is the code in the source.ts file:

```
 {
    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    var xml = "<root><Copy><Home>true</Home></Copy><More><MoreArray><name>A</name></MoreArray><MoreArray><name>B</name></MoreArray></More></root>"

    parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    var strinRes = result.root.More[0].MoreArray[0].name;
    console.dir(strinRes.toUpperCase());
    });

}
```

The output is :
TypeError: strinRes.toUpperCase is not a function

The problem is strinRes is coming as [A] instead of A. This happens only with xml2js library and also "More" is represented as an array instead of an object.

Now, how do I parse this and print uppercase of A using same 'xml2js' library?

Answer (score 1):

Your `name` variable is an array, try the following:

```
var strinRes = result.root.More[0].MoreArray[0].name[0];
```